# Как написать функцию SCSS для смены background-color от строки к строке?

Tags: sass, scss

Имеется таблица:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>orange</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>indigo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>violet</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Каждая строка имеет `background-color`, соответствующий определенному цвету радуги.
На данный момент задание свойства `background-color` для каждой строки выглядит следующим образом:

```
tr {
  &:first-child {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 0deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 30deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 60deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 120deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 180deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(6) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 240deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, 300deg);
  }
}
```

Как задать `background-color` для каждой строки через функцию SCSS? Заранее спасибо.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/XwOywo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr {
  @for $i from 0 through 6 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}n) {
      $adjust: ($i - if($i < 2, 0, 1)) * if($i < 2, 30deg, 60deg);
      background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, $adjust);
    }
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/sasha_jarvi/pen/XwOywo

Answer (score 1):

```
$bg-base: red;

//код

@for $i from 1 through 7{
  tr{
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      @if($i <= 2) {
        background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, (30 * ($i - 1)));
      } @else {
        background-color: adjust-hue($bg-base, (60 * ($i - 2)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```